# How to display image url from firebase in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a static url to the firebase image and display it on `<Image source={item.image} />`.
So for every recipe i want to display on my app iam adding it from firebase, name category all the details are added within firebase and iam just mapping in my app and displaying all the recipes, but the images do not display.

This is how my firebase image url looks like:

[image]

Now im trying to grab that url and add it to the `<Image source={item.image} />` by mapping it like this:

```
getCollection = querySnapshot => {
    const RecipeArr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(res => {
      const { name, category, description, preptime, image } = res.data();
      RecipeArr.push({
        key: res.id,
        res,
        name,
        category,
        description,
        preptime,
        image,
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      RecipeArr,
      isLoading: false,
    });
  };
```

And displaying like this:

```
{this.state.RecipeArr.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <List>
            <Image source={{uri:item.image}} resizeMode="cover" />
            <ListItem
              style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
              key={i}
              chevron
              bottomDivider
              title={item.name}
              subtitle={item.preptime}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('RecipeDetailScreen', {
                  Recipekey: item.key,
                });
              }}
            />
            </List>
```

The `{item.name}` and `{item.preptime}` are displayed but the image is not.
What am i doing wrong.

**Edit**

Solved that by removing {uri} and adding width and height
`<Image source={item.image} style={styles.image} />`

Comment: What is the definition for the Image component? Are you sure it isn't src instead of source?

Comment: tried both source and src still doesnt show the image

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong here.  Have you tried a console.log() to see if the image is actually in the array?

Comment: i get undefined and underneath the link of the image

Comment: I sounds like it might be an issue with your query. Can you post that part?

Answer (score 0):

Give a height/width style to an image and verify that the right URL is coming in your item.image.